# Javascript jumping out of loop before end

Tags: javascript

I have the following code segment evaluating an HL7 message to be transformed into XML

```
for(var i=0;i < msg['FT1'].length();i++)    
{   
    if (i >= msg['PR1'].length())
    {
       var codelength = msg['FT1'][i]['FT1.7']['FT1.7.1'].toString()
      if (codelength)
      {
        createSegment('BillingCodeDTO', tmp['Visit']['BillingCodes'], i);
         createSegment('Code', tmp['Visit']['BillingCodes']['BillingCodeDTO'][i])['@value'] = msg['FT1'][i]['FT1.7']['FT1.7.1'].toString()
         createSegment('Quantity', tmp['Visit']['BillingCodes']['BillingCodeDTO'][i])['@value'] = msg['FT1'][i]['FT1.10']['FT1.10.1'].toString()
      }
    }    
}
```

The idea is to remove any items with a null value for codelength, but if there is more than one line tiem, if the first is good and a value after that null, the first value will appear.  if the first value is null, then instead of moving to the next value none appear.

Thanks

Comment: Is `length()` a method on the objects you are working with? For arrays or strings it is not, it is a property

Comment: Yes, its a method from the objects.  it checks the HL7 message to see how many of a type of message segment exists which is then used to control the loops.  thse are working, I am testing the error cases and onyl get the problem with a message with an error.  if there are multiple segments wth correct formatting it works properly.

Comment: I think `createSegment()` is an async function, that's why JavaScript will start executing other statements once it has gone through the loop.

Comment: The problem is that it is not going through the lopp but going out of the loop before it has evaluated the rest once it finds a null